# Calculate offset of a row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am writing a server side on RoR, which uses postgresql.

Today I faced a feature, in what I need to identify the current offset of a row in the table. Client send me a unique identifier and I need to return current offset of this item.

So, I have table 'items' and model 'Item'.

Item has a unique field. Let's call it 'key'.

For instance, my 'items' table has this data:

```
id |  key
----------
0  |  abb

1  |  acc

3  |  cbb

5  |  aqq
```

If client send me key 'aqq'. I should output 4.
If client send me 'acc'. I should output 2.

If there is a way to do this without loading all the data from table and going through it in a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `... row_number() AS offset OVER (ORDER BY id)`

Comment: BTW: what should happen if there are two records, both with `key = 'aqq' ` ? Do you want the first, the last, or the average offset ?

Comment: Maybe duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712190/rails-3-how-to-get-the-row-number-from-a-model-with-an-order-by

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with these answers as such, it's a pretty terrible idea. It's going to perform *awfully* because relational DBs are really oriented toward *sets* of data; *table* is a bit of a misnomer as it implies an ordering that doesn't exist. There simply *is* no n'th row; you have to do an explicit `SORT` and then some kind of row numbering on the fly. See if you can find some way to avoid needing to do this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted it through ActiveRecord then something like:

```
Item.where("id <= ?", Item.find_by_key("aqq").id).count
```

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty simple and neat

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you could do it in PostgreSQL, I'll have to leave the mapping to RoR to someone else :)

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE key='acc' LIMIT 1 )
SELECT COUNT(Table1.id) 
FROM Table1 JOIN cte ON Table1.id <= cte.id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/91cdd/5).

If you have duplicate keys, you may want to order the cte SELECT by id to deterministically get the one with the highest or lowest id.